# Can't use ternary operator to assign Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, type-inference, linq-expressions

I just typed the following code:

```
Expression<Func<ContentItem, bool>> expression = 
                fileTypeGroupID.HasValue ? n => n.Document.MimeType.FileTypeGroupID == fileTypeGroupID.Value : n => true;
```

Visual Studio is saying it can't infer the type of `n`.

The code seems fine to me - it's just using a ternary operator to assign one of two `Expression` literals to an `Expression` variable.

Is Visual Studio just not smart enough to infer the type of `n` inside a ternary operator, or have I made some kind of mistake?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question is asked almost every day in some form.

The conditional operator type analysis proceeds from *inside* to *outside*, not *outside* to *inside*. The conditional operator does not know *to what type its results are being assigned* and then *coerces the consequence and alternative to those types*. It does the opposite; it works out the types of the consequence and alternative, takes the more general of those two types, and then verifies that the general type may be assigned.

The consequence and alternative contain no information about what the type of the lambda should be, and therefore the type of the conditional cannot be inferred. Therefore it cannot be verified that the assignment is correct.

It is edifying to consider why the language was designed that way. Suppose you have overloads:

```
 void M(Func<string, int> f) {}
 void M(Func<double, double> f) {}
```

and a call

```
M( b ? n=>n.Foo() : n => n.Bar() );
```

Describe how overload resolution determines which overload of M is chosen in a world where types are inferred from outside to inside.

Now consider this one:

```
M( b1 ? (b2 ? n=>n.Foo() : n => n.Bar() ) : (b3 ? n=>n.Blah() : n=>n.Abc()) );
```

Getting harder isn't it?  Now imagine that Foo, Bar, Blah and Abc were themselves methods that took funcs, and also had arguments with conditional operators containing lambdas.

We do not wish to make the type inference process so complex without a corresponding huge benefit, and there is no such huge benefit for the conditional operator.

What you should do in your case is cast one or both of the consequence and alternative to the specific type.

Comment: Why is casting better than just giving `n` a type (`(ContentItem n) => ...`)?

Comment: Thanks as ever for the detailed response.

Comment: Explicitly casting each lambda in this way `(Expression<Func<ContentItem, bool>>) (n => true)` fixed the problem, although the code is so ugly as to need refactoring anyway!

Comment: @Gabe: Just giving the parameters a type doesn't help. That doesn't give a type to the *lambda*. Suppose you said "(string x)=>false". What's the type of that expression? `Predicate<string>`? `Func<string, bool>`? `Func<string, object>`? There are infinitely many types it could be and no way to say which one is the best.

Comment: Sorry, @Erik, but maybe type coercion constraints is not the cause of this behavior. You can explicitly define each lambda parameter type and not rely on type coercion at all and the following code will not compile: ´Action<int> ff = (1 == 2) ? (int n) => Console.WriteLine("nope {0}", n) : (int n) => Console.WriteLine("nun {0}", n);´

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer you question of why the compiler could not infer the type, but an easy work around would be to write your expression this way:

```
Expression<Func<ContentItem, bool>> expression = 
  n => !fileTypeGroupID.HasValue || n.Document.MimeType.FileTypeGroupID == fileTypeGroupID.Value;
```

Comment: As you say, you don't answer the question as asked, but this is a very elegant practical solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
fileTypeGroupID.HasValue ? (ContentItem n) => n.Document.MimeType.FileTypeGroupID == fileTypeGroupID.Value
                         : (ContentItem n) => true;
```

---

Note the *conditional operator* is the correct name for `? :` It's an example of a ternary operator (and is the only ternary operator in many programming languages).

Comment: Since it is the *only* ternary operator in C# (and C, and C++, and many other languages) it is reasonable to call it "the" ternary operator. Most people will know what you mean.

Comment: @Jon, @Eric: Even though people know `? :` as the ternary operator and know what someone using the term means i think it's worth pointing out the correct name. Because it bugs me, that's why! :)

Comment: It's a fair point to make. I'm upvoting to restore the balance of the force.

Comment: Pointing out the correct name is good. But calling it "the ternary operator" in a context in which there is only one is also correct English, much as "put the kettle on" is superior to "put a kettle on". That said, I don't know why someone down-voted.

Comment: @JonHanna: True, i've edited my answer to put it (i think) a better way.