# Converting an if else to a ternary fails

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

Given the following

```
public abstract class Animal { }
public class Dog : Animal { }
public class Cat : Animal { }
```

I can write a method

```
public Animal UsingIf(bool returnDog)
{
    if (returnDog)
        return new Dog();
    else
        return new Cat();
}
```

Why does the equivalent using a ternary expression

```
public Animal UsingTernary(bool returnDog) =>
    returnDog ? new Dog() : new Cat();
```

Cause the following compilation error

`CS0173 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'UserQuery.Dog' and 'UserQuery.Cat`

I can work around by casting one part of the ternary (or both)

```
public Animal UsingTernary(bool returnDog) =>
    returnDog ? new Dog() : (Animal) new Cat();
```

But why can't the compiler convert the second method to be the equivalent of the first?

EDIT: I appreciate everyone's answers, but while they are correct from a technical point of view, no-one has really answered the crux of the question.

**Why can't the compiler convert the second method to be the equivalent of the first?**

This works even in the interface scenario

```
public interface IFoo { }
public abstract class Animal { }
public class Dog : Animal, IFoo { }
public class Cat : Animal, IFoo { }

public IFoo UsingIf(bool returnDog)
{
    if (returnDog)
        return new Dog();
    else
        return new Cat();
}
```

Why can't the compiler use the return type of the method as it appears to do for the `if /else` scenario.

I don't understand why the compiler is smart enough to figure it out in one scenario but not in another which is clearly equivalent.

Comment: A Dog is an Animal but a Dog is not a Cat. The error is because the type returned for both types need to be inferrable.

Answer (score 7):

The return type of the ternary operator is determined from the inside out. It determines the types of the true/false clauses and picks the more general of the two. Neither a Dog nor a Cat is a generalization of the other, so they can't be cast. But a Dog and an Animal or an Animal and a Cat will work.

From the [C# specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

> Either the type of `first_expression` and `second_expression` must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506733/cant-use-ternary-operator-to-assign-linq-expression), which elaborates:

> The conditional operator type analysis proceeds from inside to outside, not outside to inside. The conditional operator does not know to what type its results are being assigned and then coerces the consequence and alternative to those types. It does the opposite; it works out the types of the consequence and alternative, takes the more general of those two types, and then verifies that the general type may be assigned.

Comment: I've updated the question asking for further clarification

Answer (score 4):

In the first one, `Dog` and `Cat` instance is implicitly downcasted to `Animal`, separately.

However, in the second expression, the return type of the expression must be determined. So one type must be convertible to other. You might expect the compiler to just infer it as `Animal` since they both inherit from `Animal` class, but what if they were both implementing some other interface? Like:

```
public class Dog : Animal, IFoo { }
public class Cat : Animal, IFoo { }
```

Now `IFoo` is also a valid return type for the ternary operation.

This is why you need an explicit cast, to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I've updated the question asking for further clarification

Comment: you didn't, you basically asked the same question again.

Comment: Why can the if / else resolve the ambiguity but the ternary can't?